# Array not holding exact position even after swapping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to write a function for performing permutations over an array and push outputs to allPossibleRoutes array like this

```js
var allPossibleRoutes = [];

function permute(arr, start, end) {

  if (start == end) {
    console.log(arr);
    allPossibleRoutes.push(arr);
  } else {
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      arr = swap(arr, start, i);
      permute(arr, start + 1, end);
      arr = swap(arr, start, i);
    }
  }
}

function swap(arr, i, j) {
  var temp = arr[i];
  arr[i] = arr[j];
  arr[j] = temp;
  return arr;
}

var placeToCover = ["C1", "C2", "L1"];

permute(placeToCover, 0, placeToCover.length - 1);

console.log(allPossibleRoutes);
```

However, I am getting desired results in my console but the positions of elements inside array are still same as provided in input 'placeToCover'.
In my console, I m getting all the possible permutations in the form of array, but when I break array to see its indexing, it is the same as provided by me in sequence.

also, allPossibleRoutes contains the same array six times repeated which I provided 'placeToCover. Please Help

[image]

Comment: Arrays are objects, as such there passed by reference.  If you want to mutate an array and save, you will want to clone it first..

Comment: Ohh yes this was the problem! Wow thank you so much. I am using splice(0) to clone it. @Keith